# KUbuntu 22.04 plasmashell task bar does not display icons for snap apps

Tags: kubuntu, icons, plasma, taskbar

Apps such as IDEA or Slack (presumably installed via snap) lack icons in launch menu and on taskbar, but when you switch between them via alt-tab their large icons are displayed in right pane.

Why? How to fix that? I think I was on 21.04 and it worked correctly.

[image: screenshot]

Note how 1st app has icon but 2nd and 3rd don't.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to remove stale `desktop` files from `/home/ilyak/.local/share/applications/` - apparently they are not updated by current version of snap for some reason, and referenced nonexistent icon files.

This has immediately restored some icons. Bad stuff is that I no longer have these apps in launch menu - maybe I will find a way to bring them back later.